# Some Python files are not visible in my directory - Bash on Windows

Tags: python, windows, bash

I am very new to Python and Bash and I'm having an extremely weird problem where all the python files I created are not visible in the directory when I put in the ls command on Bash. I can see these files in the folder visually and it has a .py extension.

There are some Python files from Github which are visible, but the ones I have created from scratch are not. I used Sublime text editor to write the scripts. Is there something I am doing which is fundamentally incorrect?

Comment: Since you did not tell us what you did we can't say what you did wrong.

Comment: Open a terminal window and cd to the folder containing the python files. Execute the command ls -a in the terminal window. If you still don't see the files you created, they're not being saved where you think they are. Try doing a save as from the editor, specifying a full path, making sure your user account that you're logged into has permissions to save files to the directory.

Comment: Your problem seems to indicate wrong permissions on the files you cannot see. You may want to read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve], and re-word your question accordingly.